# Installing Python3.4 + Pygame on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, python3

The issue has been discussed before, but I have failed to find an answer for the problem.

I have tried both to compile Pygame from the official website and install from [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~thopiekar/+archive/ubuntu/pygame) but nothing works for me.

I still get: `ImportError: No module named 'pygame'`

Would appreciate any hint.

Comment: Since this is effectively the same question here - what have you tried? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317521/importerror-no-module-named-pygame

Comment: Have you tried with python 2.7?

Comment: yep, 2.7 is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the released version of Pygame does not support Python 3. The latest release is already packaged in Ubuntu, and you can install it with `python-pygame`, however there it is for Python 2.x only.

You need to run your script with `python` instead of `python3`.

Comment: Just "python" doesn't see the module too although the packege is installed. Should I reinstall it somehow? `Python 3.4.3 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Oct 19 2015, 21:52:17) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pygame
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'pygame'`

Comment: I don't understand what you pasted in that comment. Why does your `python` say it is python 3.4? You should never have `python` be python3.

Comment: Thank you. I see my mistake now. Python 3 is default in my terminal it runs even then I type "python". I didn't notice that.